# half circle button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

im currrently doing a wpf interface with a list of button made from he c# code, i want to make these button like half a circle but i dont know how to do it. thanks you all in advancement.

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kQWi.png)

````
buttonList = new Button[7];
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                buttonList[i] = new Button();

                buttonList[i].Content = "";
                buttonList[i].Foreground = Brushes.White;
                buttonList[i].Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                buttonList[i].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                buttonList[i].Name = "Btn" + i;
                buttonList[i].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Btn_Click);
                forzaGrid.Children.Add(buttonList[i]);
                Grid.SetRow(buttonList[i], 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(buttonList[i], i);
            }```
````

Comment: Why are you using code rather than markup? And why not an itemscontrol with an item template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your button and half circle in XAML directly:

```
<Button Width="40"
            Height="20"
            Padding="0"
            Background="Transparent">

        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    
        <Path Fill="White"
                Width="40"
                Height="21"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Intersect">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="18"
                                            RadiusY="18"
                                            Center="20,20" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,40,20" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
</Button>
```

You can wrap this into UserControl which will make it easier to add to your Grid.